# React-Native : Error while updating property 'd' in shadow node of type RNSVGPath for input string 'h'

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-svg

Facing this issue for few icons while using `react-native-svg` . I have gone through many [git hub](https://github.com/capitalone/react-native-pathjs-charts/issues/70) and [stack over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49064481/error-while-updating-property-d-in-shadow-node-of-typernsvgpath) flow discussions like these, But unable to figure out the exact root cause.

In my case I am down loading [Flat icons](https://www.flaticon.com/home) in `svg` format and then converting the `svg` to `react-native` format by using this [online converter](https://www.smooth-code.com/open-source/svgr/playground/) which is suggested by `react-native-svg` package itself.

"react-native": "0.60.5",
"react-native-svg": "9.4.0"

Can somebody tell me the root cause for this error and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Permanent solution for this issue can be found [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/issues/1080)